# C++ pointer notation

Tags: c++, pointers, semantics

So I am learning C++ right now, and I just started to get into Pointers, and I thought I would understand the semantics pretty well till iI saw this in one of the recommended solutions to an exercise int the Book I am learning with:

```
const char* sa = * ( static_cast < const char* const* > (a));
```

I understand everything aside the `const*` in the Type Parameter. Why is it there, what does it do?

EDIT: corrected unclear formulation

Comment: Doesn't your book explain it, in the chapters, prior to such code snippet?

Comment: You need to include the declaration of `a`.

Comment: `const char* const*` is a pointer to a constant pointer to a `char` that is constant. When I say "constant pointer" it means that the pointer itself is constant and can't be changed.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius No, it is in one of the recommended solutions to one of the exercises

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oooh, not I get it, thank you very much!

Comment: @patrickahrens If the book doesn't provide necessary information, to do its own exercises, you should switch it for [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Related:  a type translator https://cdecl.org/   (You'll need to give it something more like `const char* const* foo`)

Comment: You can write that type expression more consistently as either `char const* const*` or as `ptr_<const ptr_<const char>>`. For the the consistent prefix `const` notation in the last example, you need to define the type builder `ptr_` or something like it. E.g. `template< class Type > using ptr_ = Type*;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` in a type means that the type is a pointer to the type on the left side of the asterisk.

`const` in a type means that the type to the left of `const` is constant. For an object, `const` means that the value may not be modified. For a reference, `const` means that the object may not be modified through the reference.

`char` is a type that represents an integer encoded narrow character object.

`const char` is a const `char`.

`const char*` is a pointer to a `const char`.

`const char* const` is a `const` pointer to a `const char`.

`const char* const*` is a pointer to a `const char* const`.

---

Note that the pointer is indirected:

```
* ( static_cast < const char* const* > (a));
^ indirection operator
```

When a pointer is indirected, the result is a reference (lvalue) to the pointed object. If a `const char*` were indirected, the resulting lvalue would have the type `const char`. Clearly such lvalue couldn't be used to initialize the object `const char* sa`.

When a `const char* const*` is indirected, the result will be a reference (lvalue) to an object of type `const char* const`. Such value can be used to initialize `const char* sa`.

---

A simpler example without casts:

```
const char c;               // c cannot be modified
const char* const a = &c;   // a points to charcter object c
                            // a cannot be modified
const char* sa = *a;        // sa points to a as well
sa = nullptr;               // sa can be modified; it no longer points to a
```